# expressjs box api authentication

Tags: node.js, http, express, box-api

I am newbie to express and nodejs, trying to work on box.com api. As their api developers.box.com suggests, I got the authcode in the first and trying to get a token with my client id and secret. But having difficulty in getting that as I am getting 400-bad request all the times. The error is shown below

Is there anything wrong my api call? Searched on this community and with other box api threads, but I didn't find any relevant post to be useful for this. Appreciate your time and for the suggestions.

Error:

## 400 - Bad request

```
var express = require('express')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , oauthSecrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./secrets.json', 'utf-8'))
  , http = require('http');

var path = require('path');  
var querystring = require('querystring');

var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/assets')));
app.use('/lib',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/lib')));

app.configure(function(){   
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.logger());
});

app.get('/auth/box', function(req, res){
    var client_id = oauthSecrets.box.clientId;
    console.log('clientid:'+client_id)
    var provider = 'box';
    var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/box/callback';
    var boxAuthUrl = 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='
            + client_id + '&state=authenticated&redirect_uri='+ redirect_uri;
    console.log('boxAuthUrl:'+boxAuthUrl);
    res.redirect(boxAuthUrl); 
});

var authCode;  
var clientId = oauthSecrets.box.clientId;
var clientSecret = oauthSecrets.box.clientSecret;

app.get('/auth/:provider/callback', function(req, res){
  console.log('callback called');
  authCode = res.req.query.code;
  console.log('authCode:' + authCode);

  var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
    'code' : authCode,
    'client_id': clientId,
    'client_secret': clientSecret,
    'redirect_uri' : 'http://localhost:3000/auth/box/token'
  });

  console.log('post_data::' + post_data);
  var post_options = {
    host: 'https://www.box.com',
    path: '/api/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      //'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
  };
  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res2) {
      //res2.setEncoding('utf8');
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res2.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res2.headers));
      res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });
  });
  post_req.on('error', function(errData) {
    console.log('====error:' + errData);
    console.log('====error:' + errData.stack); 
  });

  // post the data
  post_req.write(post_data);
  post_req.end();

});

app.get('/auth/box/token', function(req, res){
  console.log(res);
});

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
  console.log('home called');
  res.render('home');
});

if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
}
```

Comment: redirect_uri of localhost only works if your application has not been published on the app marketplace.  It is meant for development mode only.

Comment: yes, this is my development code only. This is my development local code and am trying to auth with box. What do I need to do if I want to  call the auth api from my development localhost?

Comment: Then http://localhost will work fine.  I don't see your code to do the call to the https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token

Comment: yes, it is calling indeed. See below section in the code.                            `var post_options = {`
    host: 'https://www.box.com',
    path: '/api/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      //'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
  };`

Comment: I resolved this problem with `passport` module. I have no idea why above code was not functioning properly.